# How to add Microdata to Blogger posts?

Tags: html, blogger, microdata

How can I put Microdata into my Blogger post?

I am searching over the Internet for the past hour but I am not able to find anything.

When I use the Google Structured Data Marker, it gives me HTML but I don't know where to put that HTML.

Comment: Try contacting Blogger to see if this is actually possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying Markup Helper.
Go to webmaster tools > Search Appearance > Data Highlighter, there you can add data and publish them.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the template of your *Blogger* blog. There you could add your Microdata to the HTML.

Documentation at support.google.com: [Edit the HTML of your blog's layout](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46870?hl=en)